# TypeORM transactions not working as expected

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am having a scenario where I need to save a record first and create few more tables when the record is saved successfully. But I don't want any of these things happening isolate. What I mean by this is if there are some issues in tables creation I want the saved record to be rollback and similarly if there are some issues in saving the record I don't want to proceed with tables creation. For this, I have used TypeORM transactions.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { getManager, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { CreateTenantDto } from './dto/create-tenant.dto';
import { UpdateTenantDto } from './dto/update-tenant.dto';
import { Tenant } from './entities/tenant.entity';

@Injectable()
export class TenantService {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Tenant)
    private tenantRepo: Repository<Tenant>
  ) { }

  async create(createTenantDto: CreateTenantDto) {

    try {
      const { tenant_id, tenant_name } = createTenantDto
      const tenant = new Tenant()
      tenant.tenant_id = tenant_id
      tenant.tenant_name = tenant_name
      const createdTenant = await this.createTenantSchema(tenant_id, tenant)
      return {
        success: true,
        message: "Tenant created successfully!",
        data: createdTenant
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return {
        success: false,
        error: "Problem in creating tenant!"
      }
    }
  }

  async createTenantSchema(tenant_id: string, tenant: Tenant): Promise<void> {

    await getManager().transaction(async transactionalEntityManager => {
       
      // Step 1: Save the record
      await transactionalEntityManager.save(tenant);
      
      // Step 2: Create first table
      await transactionalEntityManager.query(`
      CREATE TABLE ${tenant_id}__customer(
        customer_id int primary key auto_increment,
        firstname varchar(255),
        middlename varchar(255),
        lastname varchar(255),
        address varchar(255)
      )`);
      
      // Step 3: Create second table query
      await transactionalEntityManager.query(`
      CREATE TABLE ${tenant_id}__product (
          product_id int primary key auto_increment,
          product_name varchar(255)
      )`);
    });
  }
 
}
```

What I tested is, I made some syntax errors (removed the `TABLE` string form the second query). But with no luck, the record is saved and the first table is created. This is something not expected with transactions, I guess. What am I missing over here?

P.S: I am using Nestjs for backend with TypeORM and MYSQL Database.